# Button assigned with function wont do as i tell it too

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, button, assign

Im trying to create a script. The goal is that the user will put in 3 numbers in 3 boxes, and click a button to display the highest number inside a forth box displayed in the bottom.

For some reason the code i have created does not do what i have written and i do not understand why. Any hints of what the problem is so i can dig into it myself is appreciated!

Here is a live veiw in browser on how it looks so you can see what happens when i press the button.

https://gyazo.com/1f825e84930891f8727aed6032b94edd

```
function checkNumbers(){

    //(Check all the numbers the user put in)
    var box1 = document.getElementById("userFill1").value*1;
    var box2 = document.getElementById("userFill2").value*1;
    var box3 = document.getElementById("userFill3").value*1;

//(If box1 > b2 & b3 write box1 value in "answer")
if(box1 > box2 && box3){
document.getElementById("answer").value = box1;
}

//(Same as above but with box 2)
else if(box2 > box1 && box3){
    document.getElementById("answer").value = box2;
}

//(Same as above but with box 3)
else if(box3 > box1 && box2){
    document.getElementById("answer").value = box3;
}

//(If no statements above is true, alert this)
else{
    alert("Vänligen fyll i med endast siffror och olika värden i varje fält");
}

}
```

Comment: Ok i somehow solved the problem, what i did was this 

else if(box2 > box3 && box1)

else if(box3 > box1 && box2)

Rotated the numbers in the else if statements, why did this make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use document.getElementById("answer").value = Math.max(box1,box2,box3)
instead of all this ifology

Comment: Helllo, Math.max is not something we have been looking at yet, and i suspect that all our assgnments can be done in a faster and better way if we only knew these others ways. I think they want us to solve problems as we go based on what we have been though recently if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Niqqo the problem is how you are comparing variables, in your first `if` you are checking if box1 is greater than box2 and **if box3 is not `0`**. What you really want to do is `if(box1 > box2 && box1 > box3)`. I understand that you tried to compare if box1 greater than box2 and at the same time greater than box3, but that is not possible, you have to split the condition.

In `if` statement you have to be really clear on which condition.

Comment: Im not sure why i can't check if box1 is greater than box2 & 3 at the same time. Is that just "how it is" or is there a good explanation why this is not possible the way i have done it? :) 

Cheers! :)

Comment: Yes... actually it is how it works, you just can't. No problem buddy ! Hope you can solve your problem !